# Removing else-if-elseif.. in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know if and there is some way to get rid code like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION parent_function (json json, OUT response_status integer, OUT response json) RETURNS record
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

DECLARE
BEGIN
    if <condition> then
      <function_call1(json,response_status,response)>;      
      return;
    elsif <condition> then
       <function_call2(json,response_status,response)>;      
      return;
    elsif <condition> then
      <function_call3(json,response_status,response)>;     
      return;
    end if; 
END;
$$
```

I would like to move these conditions into separate functions where I would like based on what the function returns(there are some output parameters I need) terminate parent function without throwing exceptions and catch them in parent function?

What I would like to achive code like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION parent_function (json json, OUT response_status integer, OUT response json) RETURNS record
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

DECLARE
BEGIN
    <check_function1(json,response_status,response)>;
    <check_function2(json,response_status,response)>;
    <check_function3(json,response_status,response)>;
END;
$$
```

After calling message and output parameters set from function terminate further processing. Is it somehow posible?

Thanks,
Lukas

Comment: E.g. `if <check_function1_call> or <check_function2_call> or <check_function3_call> then return; end if;`? (they need to return `boolean` though)

Comment: This is unclear to me. What is a parent function? How is `<function_call>` related to `<check_function1>`?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your answers. I have modified a bit my scenario to be more clear. I have a there out parameters that are returned from the functions. There are a lot of if-elseif statements in our project. And my goal is to make the parent_function more readable by moving those conditions into separate functions and if one condition fails it should not enter the next function.

Comment: I believe, I already posted an example which does exactly what you want. you cant terminate main function from another function within, you must read the data from check function and then decide continue to next check or return status and terminate further execution. calling "return"  function terminates immediately.  It isnt possible to do this as elegant as you described in the second code

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this example?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aa_test_check1(  IN test_value integer)
  RETURNS TABLE( problem boolean , problemmessage text ) AS
$BODY$
begin
problem := false;
if $1 <10 then
problem := true;
problemmessage := 'integer is smaller than 10';
end if;
return next;
end;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE; 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aa_test_check2(  IN test_value integer)
  RETURNS TABLE( problem boolean , problemmessage text ) AS
$BODY$
begin
problem := false;
if $1 >20 then
problem := true;
problemmessage := 'integer is greater than 20';
end if;
return next;
end;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE; 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aa_test_check3(  IN test_value integer)
  RETURNS TABLE( problem boolean , problemmessage text ) AS
$BODY$
begin

problem := false;
if $1 =10 then
problem := true;
problemmessage := 'something is wrong, it cant be 10';
end if;
return next;
end;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE; 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aa_test_main(  IN test_value integer)
  RETURNS TABLE( status_id integer , problemmessage text ) AS
$BODY$
declare
 temp_problem boolean;
 temp_problemmessage text;
begin

status_id :=  0;
problemmessage := 'no problem, none at all';

select * from  aa_test_check1($1) 
into temp_problem, temp_problemmessage;

if temp_problem then 
   status_id :=  1;
   problemmessage := temp_problemmessage;
   return next;
   return;
end if;

select * from  aa_test_check2($1) 
into temp_problem, temp_problemmessage;

if temp_problem then 
   status_id :=  2;
   problemmessage := temp_problemmessage;
   return next;
   return;
end if;

select * from  aa_test_check3($1) 
into temp_problem, temp_problemmessage;

if temp_problem then 
   status_id := 3;
   problemmessage := temp_problemmessage;
   return next;
   return;
end if;

return next;

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100
  ROWS 100;
  select * from aa_test_main(10)
```